# JAVA matchers group

Tags: java, regex-group

I'm building a  simple twitter user mention finder using regex.

```
public static Set<String> getMentionedUsers(List<Tweet> tweets) {
    Set<String> mentionedUsers = new TreeSet<>();
    String regex = "(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\\\.]))@([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]+)";

    for(Tweet tweet : tweets){
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(tweet.getText().toLowerCase());
        if(matcher.find()) {
            mentionedUsers.add(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
    return mentionedUsers;
}
```

And it fails to find match if the expression is in the end of text for example "@*glover* tell me about @*GREG*" it returns only "@*glover*".

Comment: Are you keeping in mind that group(0) is the entire match of your regex, while group(1) will be what's inside the first capturing group you defined in your regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to keep looping with matcher.find() over a single tweet until you do not find any more matches, you currently check each tweet only once.

(Sidenote: You should compile the pattern outside of your for-loop, even better would be to compile it outside of the method)

```
public static Set<String> getMentionedUsers(List<Tweet> tweets) {
    Set<String> mentionedUsers = new TreeSet<>();
    String regex = "(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\\\.]))@([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]+)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    for(Tweet tweet : tweets){
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(tweet.getText().toLowerCase());
        while (matcher.find()) {
            mentionedUsers.add(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
    return mentionedUsers;
}
```

Comment: Men... I was about to going to post the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `matcher.group(0)` to your `Set`, take a look to the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int))

> Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group().

The capturing group start from 1, see the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)

> **Group number**
>
> Capturing groups are numbered by counting their opening parentheses
> from left to right. In the expression ((A)(B(C))), for example, there
> are four such groups:
>
> 1     ((A)(B(C)))
>
> 2     (A)
>
> 3        (B(C))
>
> 4        (C)
>
> Group zero always stands for the entire expression.
>
> Capturing groups are so named because, during a match, each
> subsequence of the input sequence that matches such a group is saved.
> The captured subsequence may be used later in the expression, via a
> back reference, and may also be retrieved from the matcher once the
> match operation is complete.